# How to get data from cursor using Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am using this query to get data from Database using `Room` but not able to figure  out what will be the return type of this query and how to get data from that query

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(Unit), Age as COUNT from test where Age in (1, 2, 3) and Unit in ("U5", "U6", "U4") group by Age")
```

The output I a got while running in sqllite online is shown below in screenshot. So its like key, value pair.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Modify the query to name both pieces of output:

```
SELECT COUNT(Unit) as count, Age from test where Age in (1, 2, 3) and Unit in ("U5", "U6", "U4") group by Age
```

Step #2: Create a POJO that matches the query output:

```
class AgeCounts {
  public int count;
  public int age;
}
```

Step #3: Have the DAO method (on which your `@Query` will go) return a `List` of your POJO class (e.g., `List<AgeCounts>`), perhaps wrapped in a reactive type (e.g., `LiveData<List<AgeCounts>>`, `Single<List<AgeCounts>>`):

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(Unit) as count, Age from test where Age in (1, 2, 3) and Unit in ("U5", "U6", "U4") group by Age")
List<AgeCounts> getAgeCounts();
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this one